# Making columns wider using stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

So I'm making a table with my regression coefficients using stargazer and I can't figure out how to make the columns wider.

```
stargazer(fit2, fit3, type="html",
          dep.var.labels=c(""),
          covariate.labels=c("PVI","Research Level","Minority Serving Institution", "Women's College", "Prestige","Control Level (private = 1)", "Intercept 1", "Intercept 2"), keep.stat = "all", 
          title =  "Table 1. Ordered Logit Estimates of Chicago Statement Endorsement",
          ord.intercepts = TRUE,
          column.sep.width = "20pt",
          out="models.htm")
```

Here's my code. It doesn't matter what value I put in for column.sep.width, the columns don't move.

Answer (score 0):

`stargazer` with `type="html"` returns html texts. You can insert html styling, for example, for fixed column widths, e.g., `<col width="20">...<col width="20">`.

```r
library(stargazer)

linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning 
               + raises + critical, data=attitude)
linear.2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)

attitude$high.rating <- (attitude$rating > 70)
probit.model <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical + advance, data=attitude,
                    family = binomial(link = "probit"))

tbl <- stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title="Regression Results",
          type="html")

set_html_tbl_widths <- function(stargazer_html_obj, 
                                width_left=30, 
                                width_cols=rep(20, num_cols), 
                                num_cols=3, filename=NULL) {
  html_line <- c(paste0('<col width=',as.character(width_left),'>'))
  num_cols <- length(width_cols)
  for (col in 1:num_cols) {
    html_line <- append(html_line,
                        paste0('<col width=',as.character(width_cols[col]),'>'))
  } 
  new_html <- c(stargazer_html_obj[1:2], html_line, 
                stargazer_html_obj[3:length(stargazer_html_obj)])

  if (!is.null(filename)) {
    write(new_html,    
          file=filename)
  }
  return(new_html)
}

set_html_tbl_widths(tbl, 
                    filename="models.html")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely follow. So in the function you just wrote what value would I have to adjust and where in order to change the column width?

Comment: `width_left=30` is for the variable column width 30 pixels, followed by `width_cols=rep(20, num_cols)` for each column with width 20 pixels.  You can copy the function `set_html_tbl_widths()` above, customize, and run it.